# Tiles displayed incorrectly in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am currently using OpenLayers 6.5.0 to display some maps. I'm using tiles to load in the maps. All the maps are displayed correctly and the user can drag horizontally (left and right) to view the map. However, for a particular map, I'm getting incorrect tiles displayed (please see my attached image). You can see that at the prime meridian, the right side of the map is at a different zoom level than the left side of the map. When the user drags through the map, it does not look continuous. My code (using javascript and Openlayers) to create the map is pretty simple:

```
let tileLayer = new TileLayer({source: new XYZSource({attributions: '', url: xmlElement.attr("url") + '/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'})});
});

let map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [tileLayer],
    view: new View({
        center: [0.0, 0.0],
        constrainResolution: false,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoom: 2
    })
```

(the actual source URL cannot be accessed publicly)

Anyone know what can be causing this incorrect display of the tiles? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have an EPSG:4326 tile source https://codesandbox.io/s/xyz-esri-4326-512-forked-6eshil?file=/main.js  You may also need to confirm the tile size being served.

Comment: Hi Mike - you are correct. The source map was using EPSG:4326 and my other maps that were displaying correctly were using EPSG:3857.  Thank you so much for your help!